# T-SQL RegExp to find sequential repeated characters

Tags: regex, t-sql

I'm looking for a RegExp to find duplicated characters in a entire word in SQL Server and Regular Expressions (RegExp). For Example:

```
"AAUGUST"     match (AA)

"ANDREA"      don't match (are 2 vowels "A", buit are separated)

"ELEEPHANT"   match (EE)
```

I was trying with:

```
SELECT field1
FROM exampleTable
WHERE field1 like '%([A-Z]){2}%'
```

But it doesn't work.

I apreciated for your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Despite even MS misleadingly suggesting otherwise, `LIKE` does not support regular expressions. The patterns it supports are more powerful than simple string searches, but significantly less powerful than regular expressions. That said, although `LIKE` is unlikely to be of use here, there might well be a totally different way of achieving what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking with T-SQL's  `LIKE`.

Your best bet is to look at using the [Common Language Runtime (CLR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration), but it can also be achieved (albeit **painfully** slowly) using, for example, a scalar value function as follows:

```
create function dbo.ContainsRepeatingAlphaChars(@str nvarchar(max)) returns bit 
as begin
    declare @p int, -- the position we're looking at
            @c char(1) -- the previous char

    if @str is null or len(@str) < 2 return 0;

    select @c = substring(@str, 1, 1), @p = 1;

    while (1=1) begin
        set @p = @p + 1;                 -- move position pointer ahead
        if @p > len(@str) return 0;      -- if we're at the end of the string and haven't already exited, we haven't found a match
        if @c like '[A-Z]' and @c = substring(@str, @p, 1) return 1; -- if last char is A-Z and matches the current char then return "found!"
        set @c = substring(@str, @p, 1); -- Get next char
    end
    return 0; -- this will never be hit but stops SQL Server complaining that not all paths return a value
end
GO

-- Example usage:
SELECT field1
FROM exampleTable
WHERE dbo.ContainsRepeatingAlphaChars(field1) = 1
```

Did I mention that it would be slow?  Don't use this on a large table.  Go CLR.

Comment: I think you're right. Maybe the best option is use "like" with all the options:

like '%AA%' or
like '%BB%' or
...
etc

Comment: That will be slow as well, in fact I'd wager that it would be slower than my function above, but if CLR really isn't an option then it would be worth running a few tests to see what sort of performance you are going to get using the two methods with your data set